# Tableview seperator appears as a triangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

Is there a way to get a tableview seperator effect like the screenshot below, the effect has been used in the fast company app and shows two rows in the views being separated by a triangular seperator.

Any pointers on how this effect can be achieved in a tableview would be highly appreciated. The seperator at the bottom of the screen is semi transparent and the image associated with the next row shows through.

A link to the screenshot is here: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/jjm.so/17427B2C-3837-4428-B82E-8D1C57BFA706B53CD936-AE93-4F2A-B3DB-7F7018A02CBA.jpg

Comment: I think it's just a large custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this effect would be too manually edit the bottom of the image yourself using an image editor. Then you would also have to set the background color of the cell to clear. Then adjust the frame of the table cells to stretch up to give the the effect of it being under the previous cell.

Comment: Any suggestions on how this can be achieved? "adjust the frame of the table cells to stretch up to give the the effect of it being under the previous cell", any example code or a similar implementation or tutorial link would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There you go:**

```
    CGRect frame = imageView.bounds;

    UIBezierPath *path   = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height-60)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height-20)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height-60)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [path closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *mask   = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.path            = path.CGPath;
    mask.strokeColor     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    mask.fillColor       = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    [imageView.layer addSublayer:mask];
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the code, it works great and draws the separator, i need help in figuring out how to place the next row's image behind this separator. The next row image starts appearing behind the mask at the bottom of the first row.

Comment: also, how do i make sure that the table row spans the entire height of the device screen on various screens. The height of the row is changing on each phone device.

Comment: for height just get screen dimensions. search the net for it.

Comment: I didn't notice that this was your question. to let cells overlap. set the top constraint of the image view with negative value. set background colors to transparent. for each cell and all subviews set clip subviews value to false. you need also to customise image views border to get shaped borders https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html. you may also need to rearrange cells order when displaying it in cellWillDisplay method by calling sendToBack and bringToFront methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use ImageMasking on that, It may be Help you. Just simple create Image of Layer which is you required.and then Just add masking too Image.

Comment: I tried creating a CALayer shape on a label placed at the lower edge of the row, it created the triangular shape for the seperator, but the desired effect is to have the next row's image peeping through the seperator. My screen is posted here:

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a custom `UIView` inside the cell that is created by drawing a `bezierPath`to get the shape. The UIView is having a colour of 0,0,0 and alpha of 0.3-0.4 and is a subview of the `cell.contentView`. The tableview has separator as None,and the custom view lies at the bottom of the cell, thus rendering the effect that it is being used as a custom separator of triangle shape.

Comment: you are right, how to achieve the effect of the second row's image appearing where the triangle ends? The effect has a triangle shaped separator but you can see the next row's image partially behind the triangle. Scrolling up loads the next row.

Comment: The image will fill up the whole cell contentview, and the custom view will sit on the bottom of the customview above the imageview.

Comment: I am using a label at the bottom of each cell to get the triangle shape, the shape appears as expected, am struggling to figure out how to show the next row's image snippet inside this semi transparent separator.

Comment: you can do the same thing and create another `custom view` and fit it inside the content view of the cell at the top, Jst check `if (indexpath.row == 0)` meaning first cell, then hide the top customview and voila :)